# Scaling signal voltage from 0 to 5 V

Tags: rotary

I have a rotary 5 V potentiometer with a center point of 2.5 V, that only reads a max of 3.8 V and a min of 1.2 V due to mechanical restrictions I can not give the pot and more movement.

Is there a way I can scope this up to 4.5 V max and a of 0.5 V min? I have a very good 5 V input.

Please give it to me in simple terms as I don't fully understand diagram terminology.

Comment: You need a negative voltage, and something higher than 5V if you don't want to use active circuits. Or you can use a rail to rail opamp.

Comment: Please stick with *one* way to say "a potential of X Volts"; the right way is "number-space-capital-V". You used pretty much all ways that are unusual in EE; I'll edit your question to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a very good 5 V input

If your "very good 5V input" is an ADC input with sufficient resolution AND accuracy I wouldn't bother rescaling. Converting a span-range of 2.6 volts to a range of 4 volts is like adding ADC resolution of less than 1 bit whereas, if you you sampled the signal 4 times and averaged, you will likely obtain 1 bit increase due to what is known as ADC process gain.

This works if you can oversample the signal by 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your pot is connected between the GND and +5V:

As commented, you need other supply than +5V to get the wanted voltage range from the limited range pot. You need  + and - voltages.

Other solution is to add a scaling amplifier. It's a normal differential amplifier that needs an opamp and 4 resistors. It subtracts the wanted offset and makes the range wider by amplifying. No extra power supplies in addition to +5V is needed.